# Using TypeORM migrations, how do I specify a particular connection?

Tags: database-migration, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM and trying to run a migration on a test connection. In my `ormconfig.json`, I specify two separate connections as follows:

```
[{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "username",
  "password": "",
  "database": "database",
  "entities": [
    "build/entity/**/*.js"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "build/migration/**/*.js"
  ],
  "synchronize": false,
  "autoSchemaSync": true,
  "logging": false,
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
},
{
  "name": "test",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "username",
  "password": "",
  "database": "database-test",
  "entities": [
    "build/entity/**/*.js"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "build/migration/**/*.js"
  ],
  "synchronize": false,
  "autoSchemaSync": true,
  "logging": false,
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
}]
```

How do I specify the connection with name `test` from the TypeORM CLI?  I'm trying things like:

```
typeorm migrations:run -c test
```

but I'm not having any luck.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though you said you weren't having luck with that, that's exactly what I do. Perhaps some supporting information will help. My exact migration command looks like this (I'm using TypeScript and so I'm running things through `ts-node` first):

```
$(npm bin)/ts-node $(npm bin)/typeorm migration:run -c test
```

in my `ormconfig.json`, I've specified that there's a default and test connection, just like yours.

Perhaps it's as simple as saying "migration" rather than "migrations" like you have? When I use "migrations" I just get the help information printed out. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: That was exactly my issue.  It was just a typo that caused me that grief.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: This was a problem I was having too, typeorm wasn't reading my `ormconfig.ts` and I had to use the `$(npm bin)/typeorm` path for it to work.

Comment: What if I want to use both connections within the migration? (I'm copying data from one DB into another)